# Not able to click a button which sites inside form which sits under Iframe which sits under table

Tags: webdriver

I want to click a button**-Create Order** which sits under Iframe. In order to do that I need to switch my driver to iframe , for which I need to find iframe first. Now I have tried everything to locate this iframe.When I started digging in I relaized that if I do this

```
WebElement table= dr.findElement(By.xpath(or.getProperty("html/body/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]")));
```

I get some value for the table.size()

But if I do this :

```
WebElement table= dr.findElement(By.xpath(or.getProperty("html/body/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]")));
```

I get 0 count.

I have spent so many hours to get to this frame.When I failed with cssSelector or xpath I started going by each node and that's how I found this.
Please help.

Comment: Iframe is under tr[3]
form is under Iframe
Button is under form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java, you can address an iframe with `SwitchTo().Frame()` in three ways

1. By iframe name or id.  If the iframe has `name="frameName"` or `id="frameID"`, you can use `dr.SwitchTo().Frame("frameName")` or `dr.SwitchTo().Frame("frameID")`.
2. By iframe element.  You can address an iframe by something along these lines:
   `dr.SwitchTo().Frame(dr.findElement(By.Css("table>tbody>tr:nth-child(3)>iframe")));`
3. By count, starting from 0.  You can address an iframe by:
   `dr.SwitchTo().Frame(0)`, which would switch to the first iframe.

For #2, we can give you better help on a CSS selector if you include some html including the iframe in question, and a few lines above it in your question.

Comment: Thanks Richard.
The problem was that I had to switch to the window first as it was the new window where this iframe was. Fixing that and implementing one of the ways you provided above, I was able to do it.